# Type Mismatch when I try to save the database values in an ArrayList. How to avoid it?

Tags: java

I try to get all the "RegalID" from my Database and save it in an ArrayList, but I get the type mismatch from int and int []. I really don't know how to avoid this mismatch because the variable in my database has the value int and I need to save it in an array, which can hold an unknown number. So the ArrayList should be the way to go, but how can I avoid this mismatch?

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to int"

```
public ArrayList<int[]> getAlleRegalID() {
        ArrayList <int[]> regalIdListe = new ArrayList <int[]>(); 
        int regalid =0;
        try {
            String query = "select Regal_ID from regalfach";
            rs= st.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                regalid = rs.getInt("Regal_ID");   -> Type mismatch

                regalIdListe.add(regalid);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return regalIdListe;
    }
```

Comment: But why would you need to save a single int as an int[]? Wouldn't it be simpler to just make regalIdListe an ArrayList<Integer>?

Comment: Sorry i am stupid... i wrote int instead of Integer

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue.  This is saying that you have a list of int arrays.  Kind of like a 2 dimensional array.

```
ArrayList <int[]> regalIdListe = new ArrayList <int[]>();
```

What your code is calling for is a list of Integers.  A List can not hold primitive types like int.  So use the Integer class instead.  Java will automatically "autobox" it for you: convert the int from the database into the Integer for the list.

```
ArrayList <Integer> regalIdListe = new ArrayList <Integer>();
```